# YouTube Api (Search) Other Language..(Arabic, Korean, Etc....)

Tags: youtube-api

this time i've one Q, which is how to search through YouTube Api...
English is perfectly searched... but other language(arabic, korean, etc...) doesn't work...T T

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=(SEARCH_WORD)&start-index=1&max-results=3&v=2
=> My Access Code...

I'd like to search Arabic or Korean.. plz comment anything....

I need you guys help...

Have a Nice day~!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please try

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=%EA%B0%95%EB%82%A8%EC%8A%A4%ED%83%80%EC%9D%BC&start-index=1&max-results=3&v=2

or

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=\uac15\ub0a8\uc2a4\ud0c0\uc77c&start-index=1&max-results=3&v=2

on your browser.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The more general concept underlying the other answer is that the 'q' parameter (all parameters, really) will only accept any valid unicode character; so if the string you're trying to search on is not unicode (i.e. some other encoding set), those code points will be interpreted as unicode and thus result in a search on random characters (returning no results).